# Intel hd graphics driver

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics, display-driver

I am trying to update my Intel had 4600 graphics driver to the newest version but in the middle of it updating, the screen starts to flash every color rapidly. Once I force restart my computer, it stops but the driver is not installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most of the manufacturers are recommending to install drivers for windows 10 through windows update.If windows update doesn't work try troubleshooting windows update and recheck.